# Reactive Banana: State monad or not?

Tags: haskell, reactive-banana

I have an interface (WX) which is based on Reactive Banana.
Now I have different questions about how to really manage the status:

1. Should I consider the state as the `Behavior`s that I define in the code?
2. If the state depends on external "events" too, not only related to the GUI would be better considering IORef?
3. Or Can I use State Monad? All the examples I saw till now define the network in IO environment. Have any sense stack `State Monad` and how? With `Moment`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should I consider the state as the Behaviors that I define in the code?

For most scenarios you will indeed want to use `Behavior`s for state. In a GUI application you will often want to update your state in response to interface events. In addition, and crucially, the state must remain existing between occurrences of the events, and `State` doesn't allow that. More specifically, the standard way to react to an event occurrence doing something other than updating a `Behavior` is through the `reactimate` function:

```
reactimate :: Frameworks t => Event t (IO ()) -> Moment t ()
```

The action to be performed is of type `IO ()`. While it is possible to use `runStateT` to run a `StateT s IO` computation using `reactimate`, the computation will be self-contained, and you won't have the state it used available to be passed elsewhere. This problem does not arise when using `Event`s to update `Behavior`s through the reactive-banana FRP interface: the `Behavior`s remain there until you need to use them again.

> If the state depends on external "events" too, not only related to the GUI would be better considering IORef?

Not necessarily. In many cases you can use the tools in [`Reactive.Banana.Frameworks`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reactive-banana-1.2.1.0/docs/Reactive-Banana-Frameworks.html) such as `fromAddHandler` and `newEvent` to create `Event`s that are fired when external I/O actions happen. That way you can integrate such actions to your event network. One typical example would be [a timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24149514/dealing-with-the-current-time-in-reactive-banana): reactive-banana has no built-in notion of time, but you can introduce a tick event that is fired through an I/O action that happens at regular intervals.

That said, in some cases you might still want to use...

- ... `IORef`s (or other sorts of mutable variables, such as `MVar`s), if you have to use a library with an interface that, for whatever reason, restricts your ability to freely react to events using `Behavior`s and `reactimate`. A while ago there was [a very nice question about such a scenario involving `hArduino`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31689204/execute-monadio-action-inside-of-reactimate). The two answers there show different, yet similar in spirit, ways to have an useful event network in unfavourable circumstances.
- ... `StateT` if you have some stateful algorithm that is self-contained and whose results won't be used elsewhere in your event network, so that you can run it with `runStateT` and stick it in a `reactimate` call. Silly example: an `IO ()` action in `reactimate` along these lines:

  ```
  displayMessageBox . show =<< evalStateT someStateComputation initialState
  ```

Comment: Thank you! I liked the idea about firing newEvent when external I/O action happen. I use similar solutions for CQRS at work but never thought about using it for a GUI app.